# Field conversion function fails in Sencha Touch Model

Tags: javascript, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Im making a Sencha Touch PhoneGap-app.
I'm trying to add a field with a conversion function to a model in Sencha Touch 2.1
This conversion function is supposed to find individual letters and replace them ("convFAF").

I can't understand why it fails.

With the function in place, the list that (lists the store that) uses the model shows up blank. Xcode doesn't print any error message to the console.

My model:

```
Ext.define('Labblistan.model.LabItem', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: [
    {name: 'Group', type: 'String'},
    {name: 'Groupname', type: 'String'}, 
    {name: 'Analysis', type: 'String'}, 
    {name: 'Sex', type: 'String'}, 
    {name: 'AgeFrom', type: 'String'}, 
    {name: 'AgeTo', type: 'String'}, 
    {name: 'LowLimit', type: 'String'}, 
    {name: 'UpperLimit', type: 'String'}, 
    {name: 'Unit', type: 'String'},
    {name: 'Comment', type: 'String'},
    {name: 'SortOrder', type: 'String'},
     {
     name : 'formattedAnalysis',
     type : 'string',
     convert : function(v, record) {
     var unformattedAnalysis = record.get('Analysis');
     if (unformattedAnalysis.indexOf("-") != -1) {
     return unformattedAnalysis.substring(unformattedAnalysis.indexOf("-")).substr(1).toUpperCase();
     } else {
     return unformattedAnalysis.toUpperCase();
     }
     }},
     {name: 'formattedAgeFrom',  convert: convertAgeFrom},
    ]
},
});
function convertAgeFrom(v, record) {
    var unformattedAgeFrom = record.get('AgeFrom');
    var formattedAgeFrom = unformattedAgeFrom.replace('d', ' d.').replace('y', ' år').replace('m', ' mån.').replace('w', ' v.');
    return formattedAgeFrom;
}
```

As you can see I already have a conversion function going ("formattedAnalysis" - which works fine).

I've tried having the function inside the field definition (as per formattedAnalysis) but with the same results.
I've also tried setting AgeFrom type to Auto (as well auto and string for formattedAgeFrom

The strangest part is that if I switch record.get('AgeFrom'); to 'Analysis', the function works. It also seems to works with Group, Unit, and SortOrder but not with AgeFrom or AgeTo (the two fields I'm now interested in converting).

The data is loaded from an XML file, a copy of which can be found [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13253550/db02.xml)

I thought adding this conversion would be easy but I'm at a total loss here. Any help or ideas are deeply appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but use small case `string` as type in model. BTW whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Changing it to lower case didn't help. Unfortunately I'm not getting any error in the console. I'm using phonegap so console error messages go through xcode, not sure if this affects console output.

Comment: Solved it, thanks to your little "what's the error" haha will post solution below.

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently when using Xcode + PhoneGap + Sencha you don't get the same console output that you get in the browser. This caused me to miss what was actually causing the problem.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
```

so just throwing in a check for the field not being empty solved it:

```
function convertAgeFrom(v, record) {
var unformattedAgeFrom = record.get('AgeFrom');
if (unformattedAgeFrom != null) {
var formattedAgeFrom = unformattedAgeFrom.replace('d', ' d.').replace('y', ' år').replace('m', ' mån.').replace('w', ' v.');
return formattedAgeFrom;
}
}
```

Thanks to ThinkFloyd for requesting the error message. Wouldn't have thought to check otherwise. (Though my project in its current state cannot run in the browser, I had an earlier prototype which was close enough to throw the same error, does anyone know if there's a way to get more info to the xcode console?)